# Simple one line, native encrypt/decrypt method in Java

Tags: java, encryption

Is there a dead-simple native method in Java to encrypt/decrypt a string with a key? I don't really care what type of encryption (AES, DES, etc..), I just care that it's bound by with a key and not easily breakable.

Ideally, I would like it to be a one line solution like so:

```
String encryptedString = NativeEncryptionClass.encrypt("this is the data", "key123");
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried to google for *java AES*?

Comment: I have googled it. I have not yet found a way to do what I'm wanting without creating my own methods. I don't mind doing so, I was just hoping there would be a simple, one-line built-into-java way to encrypt a string - for those of us that just need the encryption process abstracted away in a dead-simple method.

Comment: Write your own.  You need to understand the mechanism anyway to properly set the defaults for the algorithm, so the effort to write it is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can do it in a [legiable] one-liner, but you can achieve simple symmetrical encryption relatively easily - take a look at the following example:

[PrivateExample using DES](http://www.mobilefish.com/download/bouncycastle/PrivateExample.java)

I've used the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library to good effect in the past.

Comment: Better to use AES.  DES is obsolete, and slow.

Answer (score 2):

If by native you mean, not depending on platform specific libraries, maybe [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html) might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try using **simple XOR** encryption

Comment: Downvoter: Actually, XOR with a one-time pad is the best encryption possible (if you have a secure way to communicate/store the "pad").

Comment: @HotLicks: does the answer say anything about OTP? "Simple XOR" alone might as well mean an implementation of ROT13.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato - no, XOR has much more potential robustness than ROT13, as XOR can trivially have a key as long as the data, while ROT13 is only ever itself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : "potential", "can", etc. In my opinion, the answerer needs to specify the exact condition that enable those guarantees. Otherwise, the answer is misleading, and hence not useful, in my mind. Hence the downvote.

Comment: This answer has the form of the strongest solutions possible on general purpose hardware, so your attempt to compare it to something  (ROT13) which can never be other than the worst imaginable method, is disingenuous, misleading, and fundamentally unfair.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : 1. Please remember to use @. 2. I disagree: the answer could be **extended** to describe the strongest solution - it has too many things left out (like the key-length issue you yourself mentioned, the need for "good" randomness of the key, etc.) to be useful - it's not only about the possible misinterpretation into ROT13. If it bothers you that much, feel free to edit answer, and I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: There is no possible misinterpretation of this answer to ROT13 - they are **entirely different** mechanisms, one amongst the strongest known and the other the absolute weakest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe it's not 'one line' but it seems easy enough:

make use of java's Cipher class. look here... (there are other examples on this page...)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#BlowKeyEx

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class SimpleMD5Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String passwordToHash = "0";
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            // Add password bytes to digest
            md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            // Get the hash's bytes
            byte[] bytes = md.digest();
            System.out.println(bytes);

            // This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
            // Convert it to hexadecimal format
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff), 16).substring(1));

            }
            // Get complete hashed password in hex format
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(generatedPassword);
    }

}
```